# Apple Mail App Alternatives for os X

Tags: macos, mac, email

Can anyone let me know if there are any lightweight-Mail application for Mac OS X? Mail seems to consume too much of memory space

Comment: The trouble is that mails are now full web pastes and these require a lot of memory - unfortunately you can't set recent Apple's mail to just show a text version

Comment: It's weird at times Mac-Mail takes nearly 1GB of Memory Space!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thunderbird stands out because it gives you access to dozens of community-developed extensions. Is there a feature you wish your program had? Go to the Add-Ons tab, search, and most of the time, there it is.

Here are some examples of features offered by Thunderbird add-ons:

- Display the sender's User Agent to see if he is also on a Mac or on Outlook :)
- Dictionaries in various languages
- Reminders  / event manager
- Clocks in status bar to know what time it is in various parts of the word
- Identity chooser to manage sending from various accounts
- Duplicate message remover
- Snippets

The list goes on and on.

Comment: That's interesting! Do you have any idea about how smooth is Thunderbird's integration with iCal?

Comment: @Nariman No, don't know.

Answer (score 0):

AirMail, PostBox, Thunderbird, Mailbox(Beta), MailMate, Mail Pilot, UniBox, Inky.

I personally like AirMail a lot and it is very cheap.
But you are free to use any of those. There are actually quite a lot Mail-Clients out there.